# Reload keyboard shortcuts

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, suspend, shortcuts

Each time I suspend and then resume on my Acer C720, Unity loses my custom keyboard shortcuts.

I'm talking about these:

[image]

I use them because that's where the associated keys on a Chromebook are.

Is there a command that I can run on each resume, that would force Unity to reload the shortcuts defined in Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts?

(I know where to place those scripts, and I can edit your answer to include that part. I just need the command that would re-read the shortcuts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reload the custom keyboard shortcuts as follows:

1. **Restart compiz.**

   Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   setsid compiz --replace
   ```
2. **Restart unity shell.**

   Open a run window, not a terminal, with the keyboard combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type *unity*. Click on the unity icon to restart unity shell.